# Как сложить цифры из текста

Tags: c++, строки

Имеется фаил (numbers.txt) - в нём одни цифры но они разделяются ",". 
Пример: "2,3,15,6,276,1,2000,"

Вопрос:
Как сумировать их, а точней определённое количество. К примеру, мне нужно сумировать первую и вторую, 1+2+3, 2+3, 2+3+4, 3+4+5+6+7.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Уточните проблему. Разделите на части, что вам неясно, как читать файл, как разделить строку на части, как преобразовать в цифры, как складывать?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: как читать фаил я знаю. как сказать программе чтоб она сумировала цифры из этого фаила по примерам которые я напечатал выше.

Comment: Видимо вам надо разбить входящий файл по запятым, к числам применить `atoi` что бы превратить их в `int` и их спокойно складывать

Comment: как читать фаил я знаю. как сказать программе чтоб она сумировала цифры из этого фаила по примерам которые я напечатал выше. скажем я сохранил фаил nomera.txt (в нём такой текст: "1,2,5,27,32,268,3,829,3,")в "char numbers[];"  Как теперь обяснить програме чтоб она в sum[1] = сохранила =1+2+5; в sum[2]=27+32+268+3; Мне это не понятно.

Answer (score 3):

Основная ошибка у Вас в том, что во входных данных строка, а не числа. Для начала надо разбить строку на числа, а затем уже складывать. Строку с разделителем "запятая" можно разбить на части (токены) следующим образом:

```
const char numbersStr[] = "2,3,15,6,276,1,2000";

std::istringstream iss(numbersStr);
std::vector<int> numbers;
std::string token;

while(std::getline(iss, token, ','))
    numbers.push_back(stoi(token));
```

Далее очевидно:

```
std::vector<int> sum;
sum.push_back(numbers[1] + numbers[2] + numbers[3]);
```